# Decoder's autoregressive output keeps outputting the same token

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language

I'm currently working on a personal reimplementation of the Transformer model from the paper [*Attention is All You Need (Vaswani et al., 2017)*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) and had a question.

---

Right now the way that I'm getting the output is as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


def decode_autoregressive(model, src):
    outputs = torch.ones(size=(src.shape[0],)).reshape(-1, 1) * 2

    for _ in range(src.shape[1]):
        prediction = F.softmax(model(src, outputs), dim=2)
        prediction = torch.argmax(prediction, dim=2)[:, -1]
        outputs = torch.cat((outputs, prediction.view(-1, 1)), dim=-1)

    return outputs[:, 1:]
```

To add some explanation, `outputs` is our output. It's initialized with the EOS/SOS token (which is `2` in the tokenizer I'm using). The `src` is the source language and it's shape is `[batch_size, sequence_len]`. I initialized `outputs` so that it has as many sample numbers as `src` (i.e., `src.shape[0]`).

The model outputs values of shape `[batch_size, output_seq_len, vocab_size]`. The softmax is put on the `vocab_size` dimension so that we have a probability distribution over the vocabulary. argmax is subsequently used so that we choose the vocabulary word with the highest probability. That's then concatenated to `outputs` which is again fed into the model in an autoregressive manner. I wrote the code to return the outputs excluding the EOS/SOS token because the ground-truth target tokens doesn't have them.

So this is basically a naive way to implement the decoding, which may be the reason why the decoder output is pretty much terrible, resulting in bad BLEU scores as well.

---

I'm wondering what I may be able to do her? I've read somewhere that I need to implement beam search, and another thing I've read is that rather than using a deterministic method like argmax I could select the top-k tokens and sample from there. I'd like to know if anyone else might have any opinions though. Thanks!